# Referring to original object in With statement

Tags: vb6, with-statement

I know that I can use a `With` statement to make repeated references to a single object:

```
With myObj
  .StringProperty = ""
  .BooleanProperty = False
End With
```

However, what I want to know is: is there a shorthand for referring to the original object in the `With` statement? In the above example, can I refer to `myObj` without explicitly typing `myObj` as I'm already working with it.

Comment: Can you edit the question to give an example of where this would be useful?

Comment: This is not a duplicate question, but the answer's still the same: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1152983/256431

Comment: @quamrana Being able to pass the object as an argument is an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you can't, but it wouldn't mean much anyway.  `With` just sets the default scope to the object expression that follows it.  If you need a reference to the object this doesn't help unless the object is one of the very few that has a .Self property, which is quite rare.

Comment: +1. There are a lot of objects that would allow a structure like `.Child.Parent`, but again that's not particularly useful.

Comment: I suspected as much, but just wanted to make sure.

Comment: There are times when it might be handy if you could use `.` to pick up the object reference, but it just doesn't work that way.

Comment: I miss this feature, esp. when doing `With New cMyClass ... End With`