# VBA With obj - how to reference the obj inside the With without naming it?

Tags: vba, excel

If I am inside a With block that is referencing the object I want to reference for a function call for example ,  must I reference the object by name or is there a  "this" ,"me"  ref that I can use?

I Have done a search online but not finding much about it in VBA.

```
Dim shExport As Worksheet

With shExport
    .......
    .......
    'works as expected 
    GetData(shExport)

    'but how can this be achieved without naming it
    GetData(this)
    GetData(me)
    GetData()
    ........
End With



  Function GetData(sh As Worksheet) As Integer
   .....
   .....
   End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could specify a property of the object that supports the `.Parent` property to get a reference back to the object. For example:

```
With shExport

    GetData(.Cells.Parent)

End With
```

Comment: Although this is a technically correct answer to the question, this doesn't feel like a better option than just referencing the object directly.

Comment: Of course its better, it means the code can be reused without having to retype all the variable names.  in a large file that starts with "with shname" only having to change it at the start makes plenty of sense and not looking for other references because Microsoft didnt bother to add a this of Self obj

Comment: ill just write  refSelf or  varSelf = .Cells.Parent and then its clear to other maintainers

Comment: @Degustaf: I agree. It seems to be a pretty circuitous route to get a reference to an object that you already have by name. In any case, thanks for recognizing that I answered the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to reference the object other than directly call it (also look: [How to access the object itself in With ... End With](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152983/how-to-access-the-object-itself-in-with-end-with)).

What you can do is to generically call the worksheets collection like this:

`ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")` or `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)` etc.

Regarding the with block - You can use a dot  **`.`** inside it to reference the object's child elements/fields, but you can't send the dot **`.`** as a parameter.

Comment: are you saying just use GetData(.)  ? really?

Comment: i want to reference the object that is being referenced by the with,  not a child of it

Comment: You cannot do this... if you find a way plz post here. But 10 years of vb6/vba/vb.net taught me it can't be done.

Comment: Specifically you can refer to the worksheet collection `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")`

Comment: but i already have a variable for the sheet, and i have that in the code above, i can use it just fine to call the function,  but since i am in a WITH that is referecing that object , there must me a ME or THIS, that can use the object i am currently at with the WITH

Comment: Again, you can only use the dot `.` , but I doubt it can be used in function calls.

Comment: Why is it so important for you to use a generic reference here?

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152983/how-to-access-the-object-itself-in-with-end-with