# Properties or Methods?

Tags: c#, properties, methods

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Properties vs Methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601621/properties-vs-methods)

I'm a beginner C# programmer and recently discovered how to use properties to expose members. However I'm confused on when to use a property as apposed to a method when returning something.

Should I do this:

```
public Vector2 Center {
    get {
        Vector2 screenDem = new Vector2(game.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width,
            game.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height);
        return new Vector2(screenDem.X / 2, screenDem.Y / 2);
    }
}
```

or should I do something like this:

```
public Vector2 GetScreenCenter() {
    Vector2 screenDem = new Vector2(game.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width,
            game.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height);
    return new Vector2(screenDem.X / 2, screenDem.Y / 2);
}
```

When should I use which and why?

Maybe I'm just thinking about this too hard and it doesn't matter, I don't know.

Thanks.

Comment: At the end of the day, your 2 approaches are equivalent.

Comment: @KirkWoll. It's clearly not a dup, this question is _properties **or** methods_, while your link is _properties **vs** methods_. Get real! `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to get and set a value then a property is best.

```
public DateTime TheCurrentTime {get; set;}
```

If you need to pass parameters in order to modify or return something then a method is best.

```
public DateTime HowManyDaysUntilMyBirthday(Datetime MyBirthday) 
{
    return (MyBirthday - DateTime.Now());
}
```