# Code Style: shop.AddProduct(product) or shop.Products.Add(product)?

Tags: c#, architecture, coding-style

This is a question that I've been asking myself for quite some time so I decided to just ask you guys here.

Let's assume I have a `Shop`-object which contains a `ProductList`-object as an instance variable. Core functionality of my `Shop`-object is of course the ability to add a `Product`.

**What should the public interface for adding products to the shop look like?**

`shop.AddProduct(product)`

or

`shop.Products.Add(product)` ?

Thank you for your thoughts and your help.

Comment: I'd go with the first, think it's more easily understood. Not that they are particularly hard anyway, but the first just rolls nicely

Comment: I agree, plus you don't need to access a member

Comment: I personally prefer the second.  The ability to add a new product to a list of products is a feature of the product list, not the shop.

Comment: I think it depends on the intended use of the `Products` collection. How would you feel about someone getting a reference to `Products` and manipulating it without regard to the original `Shop`? If that's expected/acceptable behavior, then I would go with the second. Otherwise, I would go with the first.

Comment: First one, easy maintenance, easy refactoring, more readable

Comment: possible duplicate of [Properties vs Methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601621/properties-vs-methods)

Comment: @JasonWatkins - Properties can be private as well.  One can just as easily get a reference to the internal collection object as well.

Comment: See Law of Demeter http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really a question about whether or not to expose Products as a property, or whether to use methods.  And there are already many questions on SO regarding this.  For example:

[Properties vs Methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601621/properties-vs-methods)

I personally prefer properties in most cases when they are not a functional part of the container object.  By that, I mean that products are not an integral part of a store.  A store is still a store, even if it has no products.

Products are simply objects that live within the store.  As such, they make perfect sense as a collection property.  Although I would probably have an Inventory property, of which Products are a property of the inventory.

In any event, methods tend to make more sense when they do something.  Not simply containing something.  For instance `store.PurchaseProduct(product)` would remove items from the products collection, but it also does something (adds money to the till, does inventory management, etc..).

Another reason to use methods is when you need to do several things when you manipulate the collection.  For instance, suppose you don't want objects removed from products without also ensuring that money goes into the till, or that breakage is recorded.  Then, I would still use a property, but I would make that property private and only access it via methods that perform the actions.

This is, however, largely a philosophical argument.  People will have opinions either way.  What matters is your own opinion.

Comment: Thank you for your well-written answer. This will be tough to decide on. How would you feel about mixing the two? `shop.addProduct(product)` looks really clean. However, I might want to get the ProductList as an array or add products from an array. I could avoid lots of duplicate implementations if I went directly for `shop.Products.ToArray()` or `shop.Products.Add(Product[] productArray)`