# How to get the sum of List object property values using foreach

Tags: c#, list, oop, foreach

### What i'm trying to do

Find the price sum for all items in a shoppingcart list.

### How i tried to solve it

I think it makes sense to add it as a property in the Cart-class.
I also think it would be logical to just use a foreach loop to iterate the CartList and add the itemprice (ProductsInCart.Price) to a temporary variable (PriceSum), which is returned in "Cart.PriceAllContent" property.

**C#**

```
//Instantiating Cart
  Cart C2Cart = new Cart();

//Getting Item in cart from Session
  C2Cart.TakeCart();

//Writing out result
  Response.Write(C2Cart.PriceAllContent);
```

**Classes**

```
public class Cart
{
    //FIELDS    
    private List<ProductsInCart> _cartList;
    
    //PROPERTIES
    public List<ProductsInCart> CartList
    {
        get { return _cartList; }
        set { _cartList = value; }
    }


    public float PriceAllContent
    {
        get
        {
            float PriceSum= 0;
            foreach (var ProductsInCart in _cartList)
            {
                PriceSum= +ProductsInCart.Price;
            }
            return PriceSum;
        }
    }

  ...........
}

public class ProductsInCart
{
    //FIELDS
    private int _id;
    private string _name;
    private float _price;
    private int _amount;

............
}
```

*Complete class code can be seen here (may not be fully updated yet. Ask if needed)
https://github.com/chmodder/PlanteskoleWebsite/tree/master/App_Code*

### Problem

Problem is, that when writing out the result, It would only write out the last items price instead of the sum of all itemprices.

```
Response.Write(C2Cart.PriceAllContent);
```

I allready tried searching for a solution, but couldn't find what i needed.
If anyone can help me solve the problem i would be a happy man.

Comment: `PriceSum= +ProductsInCart.Price` -> `PriceSum += ProductsInCart.Price`... You're doing `PriceSum = (+1 * ProductsInCart.Price)`. You can find issues like this by placing breakpoints, stepping through your code and inspecting the variables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to increment `PriceSum` variable with product price, use [+= operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa7629ew.aspx):

```
foreach (var ProductsInCart in _cartList)
{
    PriceSum += ProductsInCart.Price; // instead of =+
}
```

When you write `= +value` then its two separate operators [= operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbkb459w.aspx) and [+ operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1a63xkz.aspx) i.e. `+ProductsInCart.Price` just returns value of products, price, and then you assign this value to `PriceSum`. As result, you will have price of last product in list.

You also can use LINQ instead of this loop:

```
public float PriceAllContent
{
    get { return _cartList.Sum(p => p.Price); }
}
```

Comment: that was fast :) will try it now

Comment: Consequently to avoid any confusion, `PriceSum = PriceSum + ProductsInCart.Price;`

Comment: Such a silly little error, which has cost me hours of frustration. It is almost embarrassing, but I'm happy to tell you, that it works now :) Thanks. I will checkmark your answer in about 10 min, when the site allows me to.

Comment: Like I said in my comment, this shouldn't cost you hours. Visual Studio has one of the best debuggers out there. Use breakpoints and inspect your variables.

Comment: @lucuma `+=` if very handy operator, I don't think it should confuse you, just get used to it :)

Comment: It doesn't confuse me, but it could confuse others.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Yeah, but for some reason the debugger has been playing tricks on me in this project. It resets the Cart, when i start debug mode, which makes it hard for me to test on the Cart. About the '= +value', that was just a typo, but i did try it with 'something =+ value', which I  didn't recall worked. BUt all is good now. It works and I kan get something else done. Thanks again

Answer (score 4):

The `=+` should be `+=` to fix your problem.

You can also simplify:

```
public float PriceAllContent
{
    get { return _cartList.Sum(i => i.Price); }
}
```

Although as a convention, I'd use a method `CalculatePriceAllContent()` instead of a property,  to signify to the caller that you are doing a calculation and not just getting a stored value. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/601648/1094268

Comment: A sum operation is not computationally complex nor does it produce side effects.

Comment: @CodeCaster That depends what they mean by complex. It's actually does some calculations, that's my point. What if you have millions of objects in the list? It's `O(n)`, instead of `O(1)` which I'd like to expect for a property.

Comment: I think I will wait with LINQ until I have learned it. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

```
        int sum1;
        List<int> num = new List<int>() {1,2,3,4,5 };
        sum1 = num.Sum();
        Console.WriteLine(sum1);
```