# Why in Javascript calling method is different than calling getter/setter method

Tags: javascript

for example, here is a snippet of code

```js
let myQuestion = {
  _greeting: 'Hello',
  
  sayHello() {
    console.log(this._greeting);
  },
  
  get sayHelloWithGet() {
    console.log(this._greeting);
  }
};

myQuestion.sayHello();
myQuestion.sayHelloWithGet;
```

Both of them did the same thing, both of them are called method, but why different usage?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

Comment: One is a method, the other is a property accessor. They provide a different way of interacting with an object.

Comment: Not Javascript, but the same principles apply: https://stackoverflow.com/a/601648/149436

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...both of them are called method...

Not usually. Usually getters and setters are called getters and setters, or collectively "accessors" (but yes, sometimes "accessor methods").

> ...but why different usage?

Because that's the point: Sometimes you want those different semantics at point of use, something that looks like a simple property access even though it runs a function under the covers. Methods are verbs, non-method properties are nouns.

(Of course, when disguising a function call as a property access, it's incumbent upon the programmer to ensure that the cost of reading the property is low.)

---

Vaguely related: Properties with accessors are also included in various serializations, whereas properties referencing functions typically aren't. Example:

```js
var o = {
  get foo() {
    return 42;
  },
  bar() {
    return 67;
  }
};
console.log(JSON.stringify(o));
```

Comment: ok, I did not know what is "accessor method" before, Thank you so much ^^

Comment: @DonghuiMa: Glad that helped. FWIW, in some languages without this special property behavior, an "accessor method" would be an actual method. For instance, in Java, you'd have `getWhatever` and `setWhatever` as actual methods. But in JavaScript, C#, and a few others, they can be actual properties with hidden function calls.

Comment: once again ^^ thank you for telling me this, though it is a bit of hard for me to understand.