# "Get" keyword in a Class method?

Tags: c#

What is the difference between the two method definitions, one with `get` one without? I understand that properties can have `get` and `set` keywords, but what about in normal methods like below?

```
public bool IsEmpty 
{
    get { return _end == _start; }
}

public bool IsEmpty () 
{
    return _end == _start;
}
```

Comment: The first one compiles? You've left out the parentheses.

Comment: The second would be a method instead of a property if you would have added the parantheses `IsEmpty(){}`

Comment: Methods have to have Parameters even if empty !

Comment: Functionality your code does the same thing. However, a property and a method are conceived to be used for different purposes. Take a look here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164527/exposing-member-objects-as-properties-or-methods-in-net

Comment: Sorry everybody, I misunderstood that they were methods. In fact, they were properties. Problem solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither are method definitions. The first is a read-only property definition:

```
public bool IsEmpty
{
    get { return _end == _start; }
}
```

The second looks the same, but misses the `get` keyword:

```
public bool IsEmpty
{
    return _end == _start;
}
```

So it won't compile. Make it a [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114(v=vs.140).aspx) definition by adding parentheses:

```
public bool IsEmpty()
```

Comment: Thanks @CodeCaster, I think it is my own stupidity that I thought they were "Method".... problem resolved!